# How can I disable the Gedmo/Loggable event on Address

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I'm using Sylius and I want to disable the log of address change witch is done by gedmo/loggable.

This is added in the Address.orm.xml from the AddressingBundle here :

```xml
<gedmo:loggable log-entry-class="Sylius\Component\Addressing\Model\AddressLogEntry"/>
```

We have no use of it and the table entries go wild pretty quickly. (More than a million in half a year)

Is there any way to remove the annotation or the event ? I've tried to create a listener on LoadClassMetadataEventArgs to remove it from the doctrine metadata but it's not here.

PS: For information, I'm using sylius 1.10.13 and Gedmo 3.2.0.

EDIT:
I found a way to remove the eventListener but I don't like the solution since it disable all the possible loggable from Gedmo and not only for the Address :

```php
    public function loadClassMetadata(LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs): void
    {
        foreach ($eventArgs->getEntityManager()->getEventManager()->getListeners("postPersist") as $listener) {
            if (get_class($listener) === LoggableListener::class) {
                $eventArgs->getEntityManager()->getEventManager()->removeEventListener(['postPersist, onFlush'], $listener);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For remove gedmo/loggable only on address entity, you can use `$eventArgs->getClassMetadata()->getName()` to ensure is really on `Sylius\Component\Addressing\Model\Address::class` to remove loggable listener.

In your case the result will be :

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Shop\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LoadClassMetadataEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;
use Gedmo\Loggable\LoggableListener;
use Sylius\Component\Addressing\Model\Address;

final class LoadClassMetadataListener
{
    private const LISTENER_TO_REMOVE = [
        LoggableListener::class => [
            Address::class,
        ],
    ];

    public function loadClassMetadata(LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs): void
    {
        $eventManager = $eventArgs->getEntityManager()->getEventManager();

        foreach ($eventManager->getListeners(Events::postPersist) as $listener) {
            if (
                get_class($listener) === LoggableListener::class
                && in_array($eventArgs->getClassMetadata()->getName(), self::LISTENER_TO_REMOVE[LoggableListener::class])
            ) {
                $eventManager->removeEventListener(Events::postPersist, $listener);
            }
        }

        foreach ($eventManager->getListeners(Events::onFlush) as $listener) {
            if (
                get_class($listener) === LoggableListener::class
                && in_array($eventArgs->getClassMetadata()->getName(), self::LISTENER_TO_REMOVE[LoggableListener::class])
            ) {
                $eventManager->removeEventListener(Events::onFlush, $listener);
            }
        }
    }
}
```